# Pass Jenkins Parameter to python script in a Build

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a jenkins job with parameter "github_username" which is being passed to a python script with below line.I used a string parameter but the script is runnig against each letter of the username instead runnig against the username as a single word.
is there a better to this?

```
users = os.environ.get("github_username")
```

```py
import os
## Reading all members from file 
## with open('users.txt') as file:
##    users = file.read().splitlines()
## users = os.environ.get('github_username')

users = os.environ['github_username']
```

[image]

Comment: @stefano I tried your suggestion but the script is still running against the letters

Comment: I've created a Jenkins pipeline to test it and it worked. We need your code to better see what's going on.

Comment: I was getting users from file users.txt which is working fine when i run locally. After I used jenkins the pass the users it gives the output in the image above. That is output i get for entering obama in the jenkins parameter field

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import os
users = os.environ['github_username']
```

And in your pipeline, use something like this:

```
sh "python3 my-little-python3.py"
```